# data.table: Optimal way to assign a fixed length of random numbers but with different pool on each group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that look like this

```
global_pool <- 1:1000
dt <- data.table(
                 Group = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 15)),
                 Value = c(sample(global_pool,5),sample(global_pool,10),sample(global_pool,15))
                 )
```

I need a fixed length (say 10, `k <- 10`) of random Values for each group, coming **not** from the `global_pool` but rather the difference from it with their already existing values. I.g. if *Group A* has the numbers `1:5`, it should have `sample(setdiff(global_pool, 1:5), k)`.

I prefer not to messed up with *for loops* and I was working with something like `dt[,...,by=.(Group)]` but I didn't make it. I would love the optimal way since I am working with huge data tables.

Please note that:

- Any Group can already have `<k`, `==k`, or `>k` Values.
- No Group has already `> length(global_pool) - k` (>990 in this example) Values and so the pool has enough numbers.

Thank you!

Comment: What about `dt2 <- dt[, .("ValueDiff" = sample(setdiff(global_pool, unique(Value)), size = k)), by = Group]`? This can be followed by a merge of `dt` and `dt2` if you need `Value` and `ValueDiff` in the same data table.

Comment: @harisf Yeap that's it! I was trying `dt[,ValueDiff:=sample(setdiff(global_pool, unique(Value)), size = 10), by = Group]` which apparently does not work. Looks like I need more practise on `data.table`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! But I don't know if this is the most optimal way in terms of memory, since you're creating a whole new data frame. As you probably have figured out, using `:=` in the original data frame `dt` modifies the variables in `dt` in-place (i.e. by reference), which would constrain you to keep the original number of rows per `by`-group.